# Django and Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I was following a resource https://blog.learncodeonline.in/how-to-integrate-razorpay-payment-gateway-with-django-rest-framework-and-reactjs
Instead of using reactjs for the front end. How can i make the frontend using Django templates? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It will be same as any normal Django Project. Instead of exposing APIs you can use normal Django Templating for your response.

Had made a similar project which might help you to understand the concepts.

To run:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
python3 manage.py runserver
```

Access the frontend template page on localhost:8000/customer/template/

Access the GET & POST APIs at localhost:8000/customer/

Link to the project: [Simple CRM Project](https://github.com/codewith-arijit/Simple-CRM-Project)

If you need any help with it you can raise an issue at Github. Hope, it helps.